# Double pole breaker partial failure?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, 240v

Yesterday I was connecting a large toroidal transformer to an unused 240V 15A circuit in my apartment (US split phase) for testing. I plugged it in and I heard the breaker trip after a few seconds.

I wasn't expecting that much magnetizing current so I probed the outlet with my DMM and got a very strange reading—80V line to line and 40V between both lines and ground.

I was worried the 30+ year old breaker might have "partially" tripped (presenting a fire hazard) so I didn't think to test it with my low-impedance meter. I immediately shut off the breaker by hand and re-tested the outlet, which now read 0V (so I don't think it was ghost voltage anyway).

Does this sound like the breaker is faulty and partially tripped? I doubt it's ever tripped in its life as it's normally used for the in-wall air conditioner. Are there any other potential scenarios that could cause the breaker to act in this way?

I plan to redo the test later today and if it fails in the same manner I'll contact the landlord to have it replaced, but I want to make sure it really is faulty first.

If it is indeed faulty and I'm only using it under supervision with proper fusing on the DUT and current monitoring, are there any potential risks to using it while we await replacement? There are no other devices on this circuit; the only other 240V device is the stove and that has its own 40A circuit...so unless the breaker has some internal resistance I can't see any problems.

Comment: Well, this  is an unusual question!  Sorry to be  blunt, but what the heck are you trying to accomplish with a "large toroidal transformer"  Is it new? Used? Did you have anything connected to the secondary? Was it shorted? Breakers are pretty darn reliable, they do fail, but very infrequently. I'd suspect a defect in the transformer or miss-wiring it.

Comment: It's brand new. Open secondary; just verifying the connections. It has two 115V primaries which I have wired in series—the polarities are marked and everything. I'll double check the wiring on it but I don't feel like that's the issue...who knows! I've blown up transformers wiring them incorrectly before, but I learned my lesson there ;)

Comment: As for what it's for...it's going to be used for a high current power supply. Output ~46VDC 16.5A. My concern is less that it caused the breaker to trip (I have a soft start circuit designed for it) and more that my outlet was still live at 80V after it tripped.

Comment: Does your DMM have an "amp clamp" on it and do you have access to an individual wire to measure amp draw?   If so, you could measure the current draw and see if it's a breaker issue or a transformer issue.   Highly unlikely to be a breaker issue.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my second comment. I can measure the current draw with an amp clamp (or a shunt and my oscilliscope) but my concern isn't that it caused the trip and more that the breaker tripping didn't seem to cut power to the outlet.

Comment: This should probably  be migrated to Electronics in SE.  I DK how to suggest that, but this isn't "home improvement".

Comment: My concern is a faulty breaker, are you sure it's on-topic there? My transformer isn't what I'm worried about, I was just giving some background.

Comment: Not sure, but a tripped breaker is very common.....that you plugged a new device into an existing circuit that had no previous problems tells me that the device was the problem. Maybe both:  The device was defective and the breaker failed. What brand breaker? Some like zinsco and federal had real problems.

Comment: It's not a FP although that is the manufacturer of the main panel in our building's basement (sigh). It's a Wadsworth, which I understand to be good quality if not very, very old. For all intents and purposes let's just say I overloaded the circuit *somehow* and the breaker tripped. Why would I still be reading 80V L-L and 40V L1/L2-G? That's what I'm most worried about. I can fix the current draw issue and my final design is even fused and has a soft-start.

Comment: Are there any other devices on the circuit? One would think mid-level voltages like your 40/80 could happen only if they're a phantom coupled from elsewhere, or if there's some kind of voltage divider present possibly involving the breakers themselves. Breakers, except the GFCI/AFCI type, don't have a connection to ground/neutral and so couldn't form a divider on their own (barring some kind of between-the-poles conduction path). If you test again, it could be interesting to load the circuit with some small incandescent lamp while measuring voltage.

Comment: Nope, this is the only device on this circuit—it goes straight to a NEMA 6-15 outlet for the AC unit. I thought phantom voltage seemed unlikely since the voltage went away when I turned the breaker off by hand. My guess was that the breaker partially disconnected both poles, but the poor connection increased the resistance between the contacts, dropping the voltage. Is that likely/reasonable? I'm going to test again later with a low impedance meter to confirm it's not ghost voltage.

Comment: For a high power power supply you should be using a laminated iron core not a toroid. For a soft start we are normally looking at motor loads or inductive loads. A soft start depending on the type will still draw 3-5x the current until up to speed that is not far off based on what you have provided.

Comment: What's wrong with a toroid? It's rated for 600+VA—should be able to do 16A with the secondaries in parallel. I guess "soft start" is kind of a term I've used loosely...it's to limit inrush current both for energizing the transformer as well as charging the 16mF+ smoothing capacitors on the output. Essentially an enormous resistor and a relay fired by a capacitor delay circuit.

Comment: @flashbang -- toroidal power transformers are kind of notorious for high magnetizing (inrush) currents, although they do have their advantages (most mains toroids are laminated iron, BTW -- Ed was referring to the more classical E-I core design when he said "laminated iron")

Comment: With a high-Z meter and as the only outlet on the circuit...I'm not even sure what to say here...only way to figure this out is going to be if you can reproduce the failure mode and see what a low-Z reading says.  Besides, that Wadsworth panel is going to be nearly *impossible* to source breakers for -- even though there's no checkered history involved with it, there's no onward lineage to be had, either

Comment: Yep, that's my plan (Low-Z meter) - although I am a bit worried to trip it again intentionally :) thankfully this isn't my panel - it's my landlord's - so I'll let them deal with the hardship of sourcing replacements.